# trying to have a different color my login form

Tags: html, css

hi i have decided to face my fears of frontend development and I am having a little bit of trouble here so I am trying to put a 50 px which is a rough estimate around my login form and I wanna change the color of it so the back ground is #423075 but I want the back of the actual login section tobe #300C94 what is the best way todo this with my code

index.html

```
<html>
<header>
    <title>Login-1</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css" >


</header>

<body>


    
    <form class="form" >
              <div class="form-back" name="form-back" >
        <input  name="username" type="text" placeholder="username" required>
        <br>
        <input  name="password" type="password" placeholder="password" required>
        <br>
        <input  name="confirm_password" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
        <br>
        <input  name="submit" type="submit">
</div>
    </form>


</body>

</html>
```

styles.css

```
body{

    margin-top: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #423075;
    

}

form{
    display: inline-block;


}

div{
    
    border-radius: 10px;
     border-radius: 30px;
    background: #300C94;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;  
     
}
```

any suggestions would be great

Comment: Can you post some image or image link or something? In order to understand the situation a little bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put padding around your `<form>` tag then add a `background-color` property to define the color of the form background. You can see here, I just kept your code and just changed a small portion in the form tag css.

```
form{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #300C94;
}
```

```css
body{

    margin-top: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #423075;
    

}

form{
    display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: #300C94;


}

div{
    
    border-radius: 10px;
     border-radius: 30px;
    background: #300C94;
}

input[type=submit] {
    width: 100%;  
     
}
```

```html
    <form class="form" >
              <div class="form-back" name="form-back" >
        <input  name="username" type="text" placeholder="username" required>
        <br>
        <input  name="password" type="password" placeholder="password" required>
        <br>
        <input  name="confirm_password" type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
        <br>
        <input  name="submit" type="submit">
</div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background-color: #300C94;
```

try to put every element which you differentiate in background or any of the CSS style put it in different division.`

```
<div></div>
```

then use the CSS

```
.div {background-color: #300C94;}
```

it will provide you the flexibility to change the color of different section you can also use the section html element which is also similar to div.